# Show that there is a basis outside the intersection of proper subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U_1,...,U_m$ be proper subspaces of an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. Show that there is a basis $\lbrace v_1,...,v_n \rbrace$ of $V$ outside the set $U_1 \cap...\cap U_m$.

**Attempt:** I understand that since the subspace are proper, their dimension is less than n. So at most the intersection could have dimension of $n-1$. But how to show that an entire basis could be obtained?

Comment: The question is curious: the intersection of proper subspaces is itself a proper subspace, so you might as well assume just one proper subspace forbidden. Maybe you meant union of proper subspaces instead? (You do need to assume the field is infinite then.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\} $ be any basis of $V$. As you have noticed there exists at least one $b_i$ which doesn't live in the intersection, say $b_1$.  Now let 
$$v_i=\begin{cases}b_i&\text{ if $b_i$ is not in the intersection}\\ b_i+b_1 &\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Check that everything makes sense!

Comment: Thank you!! It makes perfect sense!!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $x_1,\dots x_k$ be linearly independent and in the intersection, and let $v$ be something outside of the intersection. Then $v+x_1,\dots v+x_k$ are all outside of the intersection. Are they linearly independent too?

Can you see how you might modify a basis using this trick?

Comment: Yes I do !! Thanks..